$(R,M)$ is a local ring, $j(A)\in M_n(R/M)$ is invertible, then $A \in M_n(R)$ is invertible

$(R, M)$ is a local ring, and $A\in M_n(R)$.  Prove that if  $j(A)\in M_n(R/M)$ is invertible, then $A \in M_n(R)$ is invertible.

Here $(R,M)$ is a local ring which means that  $1 \in R$ and $R$ has a unique left maximal ideal, which is $M$. I have proved that $M$ is also a right ideal of $R$. $M_n(R)$ is the $n\times n$ matrices over $R$, and $j:M_n(R)\to M_n(R/M), A=(a_{ij}) \mapsto j(A)=(\overline{a_{ij}})$, where $\overline{a_{ij}}=a_{ij}+M \in R/M$.
There is a lemma proved before, which is

$(R, M)$ is a local ring. If $T$ is a finitely generated left $R$-module, $I \subseteq M$ is an ideal, $N$ is a submodule of $T$, and $T=IT+N$, then $T=N$.

Suppose $j(A)$ is invertible, then there exists $B \in M_n(R)$, such that $AB+T=I, BA+S=I$, $T,S \in M_n(M)$. Then $R^n \subseteq ABR^n+TR^n$, but I don't know whether $TR^n\subseteq MR^n$. If this is true, then by applying the lemma, $ABR^n=R^n$, which implies that A is surjective.
Many thanks in advance!
(I just began learning modules and projective modules.)

The lemma's name is Nakayama's lemma. Whatever definition of local ring you used, it should have the following property.
Proposition A ring  $R$ being local is equivalent to

(1) if $a,b \in R$ and $a + b = 1$, then $a$ or $b$ is invertible.
(2) $R$ has a unique maximal (left) right ideal.
(3) the Jacobson radical $J(R)$ is a maximal left ideal. $\dots$

The proof of Nakayama's lemma should have used some knowledge about left (right) quasi-regular elements. $M_n(R)$ has a Jacobson radical $J(M_n(R)) = M_n(M)$.
Once you have $AB + T = I$ and $BA + S = I$, $T, S\in J(M_n(R))$. $T$ and $S$ are quasi-regular. $I - T$ and $I - S$ are invertible. So $AB$ and $BA$ are invertible. Then both $A$ and $B$ are invertible.

Thanks for your answer. But I haven't learned what you say, and it seems that I have much to learn. So where can I learn this "Nakayama's lemma" and the "quasi-regular"?

The lemma quoted in your question is Nakayama's lemma.  The proof should have used some knowledge of "quasi-regular", that is, $1 - x$ is invertible. I believe the idea in the proof (maybe from your book) is enough. A reference is Jacobson's "Basic Algebra II, 4.2".

Ok, thanks a lot! (I learned in Chinese, so I asked about "quasi-regular" because I am not familiar with those terms. )
